# Convert residence permit to work permit

Tags: resident-permit, student-visa, italy, work-permit

I have a long-stay student visa in Italy (D1 type) and I'm doing my master's (The first year is almost over). I got a full-time job offer, but I don't know how to convert my permit to a working permit, and the company seems unsure of the process. Has anyone been through a similar experience? What should be the steps, if possible?

Comment: @mkennedy I'm the one who asked that question you mentioned, then I was told it is better here in expats.

Comment: Hi Tamim. That was an automatic comment made by the system when I marked this question a duplicate of your migrated question!